# Firefox bookmarks sync - one way, merged, or compartmentalized?

Tags: firefox, sync, bookmarks

As of 2021 January, how does Firefox sync behave?

I'm in a predicament trying to not lose all my bookmarks

I couldn't log into firefox on desktop, so I reset the password.
When you reset the password, they erase your bookmarks on the server.

But I'm still logged in on my phone, and it is showing me from my phone my old desktop bookmarks.

Ideally I would "push" that folder to the desktop server and I'd effectively have all my bookmarks again.

But if I re-log into my account with the new password on my phone and sync, what will happen to the desktop bookmarks that are visible from my phone?

Will firefox syncing overwrite them and disappear from my phone too?
Or will it know that I have some desktop bookmarks on my phone and copy them to desktop too?

I really don't want to risk losing all my bookmarks.
I also would like to not have to manually one by copy all my bookmarks from my phone to desktop.